# Conway's functional analysis chapter 10.2 excercise 7

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

[image: n]I am unable to understand what is the underlying hilbert space here which contains $C_c^2(0,1)$ as a domain of the operator $Af=-f''$.
If I take $\mathscr{H}=L^2(0,1)$ then $f(x)=x^{3/2}\in C_c^2(0,1)$(near $0$ as near $1$ we can make is compactly supported). Here $f''\notin L^2(0,1) $

Comment: If $f$ is compactly supported then $f''\in L^2(0,1) $

Comment: Yeah actually I misunderstood the definition of compact support I thought $f(0)=f(1)=0$ is enough but they meant $supp f\subset [a,b]$ where $0<a<b<1$